# Вычисления соседних строк в таблице

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица

```
----------------------------------
record_id | period   | amount|agrm_id
1         |20.10.2012|30   |12  
2         |21.10.2012|30   |12
3         |27.10.2012|30   |12  
4         |23.10.2012|30   |12  
5         |24.10.2012|30   |12
```

В `результате` хотелось бы получить `такую картинку`:

```
record_id | period   | amount|agrm_id |diff_period
    1         |20.10.2012|30   |12    | 1 day
    2         |21.10.2012|30   |12    | 6 day
    3         |27.10.2012|30   |12    | -4 day
    4         |23.10.2012|30   |12    | -1 day
    5         |24.10.2012|30   |12    | 0 day
```

Нужно найти разницу period со следующей строкой,то есть между первой и второй,между второй и третью,третью и четвертью, ит.д.

Здесь только `record_id` уникальный, связку можно делать с `agrm_id.`(номер пользователя)

Если интересно, могу свой запрос публиковать, но оно неправильно, не получается как то.

**ОБНОВ**

record_id возрастающий,автоинкремент, но некоторые записей могуть та и не быть, то есть удалены с таблицы. Не обезятельно в таком 1,2,3,4,5,... А можеть быть и на таком порядке: 1,2,100,500,678,....

```
PS: where t1.record_id=t2.record_id+1 не прокатить ))
```

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: пропуски в record_id возможны или нет? Если нет -- то всё просто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полуфабрикат: (без 'day' и последнее значение интервала -- NULL):

```
 select a.*, datediff(d.period, a.period)
   from vf a join 
     (select a.record_id, min(b.record_id) as r1 
     from vf a left join vf b on a.record_id < b.record_id
     group by a.record_id order by a.record_id) c
       on a.record_id = c.record_id
   left join vf d on c.r1 = d.record_id;
```

sorry, порядок параметров datediff был перепутан

upd. `order by a.record_id` в подзапросе -- лишний.

Comment: +1. "для каждой строки получаем следующую по record_id, и вычитаем из даты следующей строки дату текущей".

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT r1.record_id, r1.period, r1.amount, r1.agrm_id, 
  DATEDIFF(IFNULL(r2.period, r1.period), r1.period) AS diff_period
FROM records r1
  LEFT JOIN records r2 ON r1.record_id < r2.record_id
GROUP BY r1.record_id, r1.period, r1.amount, r1.agrm_id
```

не очень красивый запрос, но на тестовых данных mysql выдает правильный ответ, вроде...

ЗЫ 4-я строка у вас, кстати, -1 дает, должна вроде быть 1, правда ведь?

Comment: Да, mysql -- он добрый. Другие sql-сервера такой запрос не пропустили бы из-за того, что r2.period не является аргументом агрегатной функции.

Comment: @alexlz, да за это его и не люблю. Ваш запрос мне нравится больше.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd ну тут получается, что не те строки берутся. можно попробовать добавить сортировку по r2.record_id. Без данных сложно тестить...  
А вообще более правильный запрос у @alexlz. У меня упрощенный вариант, который допускается в mysql, и результат не совсем предсказуемый получается...

Comment: Если данных много, создаёте вспомогательную таблицу с autoincrement-ключом, заносите (insert-select) в неё нужные данные, и уже по непрерывновозрастающему ключу делаете запрос.